# Cordova "Error: Your .idea platform does not have Api.js" when adding plugins

Tags: ionic2

When trying to install any Cordova plugin, I get this error message.

> Cordova "Error: Your .idea platform does not have Api.js"

I have also searched the entire app for the ".idea" file and found the only reference to it in the .gitignore file.

There are a few similar questions around this error on Stack Overflow, however no solution has worked for me. Updating Node to version 8 didn't help nor did removing and re-adding the Cordova platforms.

Any '.ideas'?

**My build info:**

```
Cordova CLI: 7.0.1
Ionic Framework Version: 3.2.0
Ionic CLI Version: 2.2.1
Ionic App Lib Version: 2.2.0
Ionic App Scripts Version: 1.3.7
ios-deploy version: 1.9.1
ios-sim version: 6.0.0
OS: macOS Sierra
Node Version: v7.4.0
Xcode version: Xcode 8.3.3 Build version 8E3004b
```

Answer (score 1):

So .idea was a hidden directory in the platforms folder. Removing it seemed to fix the problem and I can now install Cordova plugins again.

Answer (score 1):

Running

```
ionic cordova platform rm .idea
```

Worked for me.